# My facebook application has suddenly stopped publishing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application is iframe based canvas. It was working fine but since yesterday it has stopped stream publishing. I am not able to figure out why?. I was looking at the code of my application but I think I didn't changed anything in the code. Or I may have changed it but the publishing code is intact and the rest application is working fine. Also , I haven't received any mail from facebook saying they have blocked my publishing rights or so (nothing like that.. no mail).

Here is the code for publishing

```
 var publish = {
         method: 'stream.publish',
            name: "Check out your friend's underwear",
         link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/underwearcheck/',
         picture: 'http://dhruvlab.com/underwearcheck/appli/pic.jpeg',
         caption: 'Its time to know the inner secret of your friend. Watch what he/she wears inside.',
         message: "Hey! I checked out one of my friend's underwear. Its really funny!. Aren't you curious?",
         description: "NEW YEAR SPECIAL"
   };

   FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {  
        document.getElementById('confirmMsg').innerHTML = 
          'A post had just been published into the stream on your wall.';

   });
```

and here is the application url : http://apps.facebook.com/underwearcheck . Can somebody figure out as to why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish too frequently to a user's stream, Facebook will simply ignore additional publish requests for a period of time. It will also ignore publish requests if you start sending too many total requests in a period of time based on the total number of users you have. I have run into both blocks while testing.

Comment: 1) I do not publish frequently . only one per user and 2) I have only 50 users in that applications which is pretty low for that part.

Comment: This is not true - in all cases you'd receive an error message in response to the API call